# react native - how to hold the position when pressing load less ? it is scrolling to bottom of the page every time I press load less

Tags: react-native

const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(false);

<Text style={Styles.descText} ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={loadMore ? 1000 : 4}>
{text}

{data?.content && data?.content.length >= 160 ? <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setLoadMore(!loadMore)}  >

{loadMore ? 'Load Less' : 'Load More'}


: null}

Comment: entire return element wrapped with ScrollView with flex:1

Comment: Hi! Here are some rules by stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask try to follow these.
Please format your code with ``, than add a question and expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
BY MANUALLY SETTING SCROLLVIEW POSITION !

const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(false);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const [scrollOffset, setScrollOffset] = useState(null);
  const [scrollPoss, setScrollPoss] = useState(null);

  const handleScrollTo = p => {

    if (scrollViewRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo(p);
    }
};
const handleOnScroll = event => {
  console.log('event.nativeEvent.contentOffset',event.nativeEvent.contentOffset);
  setScrollOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
};
return (
 <ScrollView 
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      scrollTo={handleScrollTo}
      scrollOffset={scrollOffset}
      onScroll={handleOnScroll} >

 <Text style={Styles.descText} ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={loadMore ? 1000 : 4}>
 {text}
</Text>
{Data?.content && Data?.content.length >= 160 ?
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{
                 
 if (!loadMore) {
    setScrollPoss(scrollOffset)
    setLoadMore(!loadMore)
 }else{
    setLoadMore(!loadMore)
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
     x: 0,
     y: scrollPoss  
                  })
    }
    }}  >
                  <View >
                    <Text>{loadMore ? 'Load Less' : 'Load More'}</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                : null}

 </ScrollView >
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).